# Python Leveling system with increasing level XP requireemtn

Tags: python

Trying to make a leveling system. I have gotten it to work with a linear 2000 xp per level, but i cannot figure out how to make level 1 2000 xp and then level 2 2200, 3 2400, 4 2600 etc.

This is the code for a linear leveling system:
`level = math.floor( xp / 2000)`
but if i do `level = math.floor( xp / (2000 + (math.floor( xp / 2000) * 200)))` (which is 2000 plus the level * 200), then it always returns around one because as the xp increases, so does the requirement. I want to get the user's level, with that system. so if i input 7000, i should get level 3 because 2000 + 2200 + 2400 = 6600 and the next level up would be higher than that.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
level = math.floor( xp / (2000 + (math.floor( xp / 2000) * 200)))
```

You can't do a straight division to calculate the new level because each level isn't the same amount of xp. Instead you should just increment the level when a character levels up:

```
level +=1
```

Then you need to calculate how much experience the character needs for the next level.

Comment: So there is no mathematical way to calculate this? It would be nice because I'm not currently storing the level in the database, just the XP.

Comment: @GreenCobalt "So there is no mathematical way to calculate this?" To calculate what? The level? Yes there is, but it would be much easier to just store the level itself. If you want to calculate the level, you need  more sophisticated algorithm than just a pure division.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. Yes, I meant calculator the level from the xp. If its some fancy algorithm then I guess I'll just store it but I'm trying to cut down on DB calls and size.

Comment: @GreenCobalt It's not all that fancy and you can figure it out on your own. Try to do some examples by hand. Say the character has 10000 XP. What level are they? How do you calculate it?